# Javascript search for 100,000 records table performance

Tags: javascript, performance, search

I'm using Keyup event to perform real time search for a less than 500row/7Column records table. It worked fine. But if the table rows change to 1000+, you will notice that it became a sightly slow  when you are typing the the input box.

Logic inside the search function is using Regex to match each col's text for each row, then return matched results for each keyup.

My understanding is, if the first keyup fired, search function will continue   processing the matching and won't take the next keyup event until its done

Is there a way to kill previous keyup event if its still processing the search logic and process the newest keyup event?

Comment: You are looking for the `debounce` function.

Comment: You have 100,000 records on the client side? Or are you making an Ajax call to the server to get matches?

Comment: `s.indexOf(".")` is usually 10-20X faster than `/./.test(s)`, even with a `s.toLowerCase()`...

Comment: Try to build a more clever approach to search some data. Prefix tree for example. If you show a bit of code, related to your problem, we might propose a more helpful advices

Comment: @dandavis thank you  . will try this